# Magento fedex labels print

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, fedex

I am integrating fedex in magento 1.9.0.1. But for fedex certification they need to print sample label for Ground, a sample Label for Express and a sample label for International.I am unable to figure out how to print all these.

Answer (score 3):

its not necessary. fedex offer 4 types of calls.

a- rate

b- track

c- ship

d- pickup

for typical carts you can use rate and track and those calls dont need to go through approval process. on the other hand for shipping calls you must send those labels and request a special certification.

in order to receive approval for rate and track you must go to :

log into the fedex developer center: http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html

four steps are required-> 1- Download and read docs , 2-Develop and Test, 3-Certification (only for shipping, pickup services). 4- Move to production.

In order to receive an approval for rate services, tracking and fedex locator just go to step 4 Move to production and fill all the information that appears when you press "Get Production Key" Button.

[image]

FedEx will send you an email with your key, meter number and password.

with that information you can put it at your app.
brgds

For shipping and pickup you can use http://www.fedex.com/us/ship/ and create your labels there, with the current fedex.com shipping application. 
brgds!
sebastian (16yrs at fedex).

Comment: Can we create shipping labels for test account from  http://www.fedex.com/us/ship/?

Comment: fedex offers to types of developer registration keys. you must have a valid account for fedex and : a-> register for test, a meter number and gatewaybeta.fedex.com:443 will be provided to test. b-> a certification for rate and tracking in production, with your account you will receive a meter number and gateway.fedex.com:443 to process those transactions live. c-> if you need to ship (create labels), you must certificate your awbs with the help desk, finally your production meter will be approved for label creation. www.fedex.com/us/developer